# Invalid JSON reported when using unsigned integers in ctype structure

Tags: python, ctypes

Using Python 2.6, I created a nested ctypes structure as follows:

```
class TestStruct1(BigEndianStructure):
_pack_ = 1
_fields_ = [
    ("temp1", c_uint32),
    ("temp2", c_uint32)
]

class TestStruct2(BigEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ("temp1", c_uint32),
        ("temp2", c_uint32)
    ]

class TestStruct3(BigEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ("TestStruct1", TestStruct1),
        ("TestStruct2", TestStruct2)
    ]
```

I then push data into this struct:

```
elements = [0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF]
data = bytes(elements)

foo = TestStruct3()
memmove(addressof(foo), data, sizeof(foo))
```

I can print out the values one by one, which results in the expected output:

```
print(format(foo.TestStruct1.temp1, '08X'))
print(format(foo.TestStruct1.temp2, '08X'))
print(format(foo.TestStruct2.temp1, '08X'))
print(format(foo.TestStruct2.temp2, '08X'))
```

> 00112233 44556677 8899AABB CCDDEEFF

But would like to leverage json.dumps to dump the structure in JSON format. This works fine in Python 3 as seen below:

https://onlinegdb.com/rJvQ0fFvS

but returns the following error for unsigned types in Python 2.6:

> encoder.py", line 184, in default
>       raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
>   TypeError: 1122867L is not JSON serializable

I'm guessing it gets confused by the appending 'L' in 1122867**L** (0x00112233)

Do I have to add some sort of unsigned type to my JSONEncoder class?

Below is an example I created which shows the issue. Endiannessis different on the host running the script, so the output doesn't match, but it at least shows the error in action:

https://rextester.com/UAWZK83752

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this helps someone else. After debugging a bit more, I ended up in the file corresponding to the error(encoder.py) and found that I was calling JSONEncoder.default in cases where I didn't handle the instance. In this case, I was assuming c_uint32 was an instance of int:

```
class ReportEncoder(JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, obj):

        if isinstance(obj, (Array, list)):
            return [self.default(e) for e in obj]

        if isinstance(obj, _Pointer):
            return self.default(obj.contents) if obj else None

        if isinstance(obj, _SimpleCData):
            return self.default(obj.value)

        if isinstance(obj, (bool, int, float, str)):
            return obj

        if obj is None:
            return obj

        if isinstance(obj, (Structure, Union)):
            result = {}
            anonymous = getattr(obj, '_anonymous_', [])

            for key, _ in getattr(obj, '_fields_', []):
                value = getattr(obj, key)

                # private fields don't encode
                if key.startswith('_'):
                    continue

                if key in anonymous:
                    result.update(self.default(value))
                else:
                    result[key] = self.default(value)

            return result

        return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

But apparently c_uint32 in an instance of long, not int. I added long to the instance list:

```
if isinstance(obj, (bool, int, float, long, str)):
    return obj
```

And everything worked from there. The full JSONEncoder class can be found below:

```
class ReportEncoder(JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, obj):

        if isinstance(obj, (Array, list)):
            return [self.default(e) for e in obj]

        if isinstance(obj, _Pointer):
            return self.default(obj.contents) if obj else None

        if isinstance(obj, _SimpleCData):
            return self.default(obj.value)

        if isinstance(obj, (bool, int, float, long, str)):
            return obj

        if obj is None:
            return obj

        if isinstance(obj, (Structure, Union)):
            result = {}
            anonymous = getattr(obj, '_anonymous_', [])

            for key, _ in getattr(obj, '_fields_', []):
                value = getattr(obj, key)

                # private fields don't encode
                if key.startswith('_'):
                    continue

                if key in anonymous:
                    result.update(self.default(value))
                else:
                    result[key] = self.default(value)

            return result

        return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```